Minimum value of a sum of two squares without calculus
How to find the minimum value of $(1+\frac{8}{x})²+(8+x)²$ for $x>0$ without using calculus. I tried QM-AM-GM but could not solve it with it. I prefer a solution with mean inequality chain if possible but would be glad any help. Thanks in advance.

Naive AM-GM works for this particular expression. Can you share what you've tried with that? It might help if you "knew" where the minimum occurred.

@CalvinLin Sure, I tried using it as $x²+16x+16/x+64/x²+65$ then tried AM-GM with first four terms since their product is constant but it did not give me the solution.

Remind me when does equality occur with an AMGM? What do you obtain when you apply it to your "first four terms"?

@CalvinLin Well if we assign $S$ as the sum of the first four terms then with AM-GM we find $S≥4*(2¹⁴^/⁴))$ and that is 45,254... but answer must be 60 with x=2 so I dont understand what went wrong with my calculation, Sir.

Equality occurs when all the terms are equal, which in your application means $ x^2 = 16x = 16/x = 64/x^2$. However, there is no one value of $x$ that satisfies all of these, which means that equality cannot occur. Thus your approach will not work. Instead, you need to tweak the AM-GM in another way, that will allow equality to exist. $\quad$ For example, if we knew that the minimum ocured at $x = 2$, then we would want to use $ x^2 + 16/x^2 \geq 8$ and $ x + 4/x \geq 4$ etc.

@CalvinLin Oh, I understand know, thanks for clarification but what do we do when we do not know the minimum point?

Unfortunately nothing really jumps out at me. I don't know of a good way to deal with the general $Ax^2 + Bx + D/x + E/x^2$, other than hoping to find inequalities that happen to work.

Alternative solution.
Let $k > 0$ denote the minimum. Let $a > 0$ denote the minimizer. We have
$(1 + 8/x)^2 + (8 + x)^2 \ge k$ for all $x > 0$. Equivalently, we have
$x^4 + 16x^3 + (-k+65)x^2 + 16x + 64\ge 0$
for all $x > 0$. Thus, there exist real numbers $p_1, p_2, p_3$ such that
$$x^4 + 16x^3 + (-k+65)x^2 + 16x + 64 \equiv (p_1 x^2 + p_2x + p_3)(x - a)^2,$$
(Note: Clearly, $(x-a)^2$ is a factor. )
or
\begin{align*}
 &(1 -  p_1)x^4 + (2ap_1-p_2+16)x^3 + (-a^2p_1 + 2ap_2 - k - p_3 + 65)x^2\\
 &\quad + (-a^2p_2 + 2ap_3 + 16)x - a^2p_3 + 64 \equiv 0.
\end{align*}
We have $p_1 = 1$, $p_2 = 2a + 16$,
$p_3 = \frac{64}{a^2}$.
We have
$$0 = -a^2p_2 + 2ap_3 + 16 = \frac{-2a^4 - 16a^3 + 16a + 128}{a}$$
which results in $a = 2$ (solving the quartic equation, or check it by the rational root theorem, or noting that
$-2a^4 - 16a^3 + 16a + 128= (-2a^4 + 16a) + (-16a^3 + 128)
= 2a(8 - a^3) + 16(8 - a^3)$).
We have
$$0 = -a^2p_1 + 2ap_2 - k - p_3 + 65 = 125 - k$$
which results in $k = 125$.
After checking, it is indeed the minimum.

Call the expression $f(x)$, then $f(x) = \left(x^2+\dfrac{8}{x}+\dfrac{8}{x}\right)+ 65+ \left(8x+8x+\dfrac{64}{x^2}\right)$. Apply AG-GM inequality for the first block and the the second block to get the answer. Equality occurs when $x^2 = \dfrac{8}{x}$ and $8x = \dfrac{64}{x^2}$ which gives $x = 2$ in both cases. Can you finish it?

[See River's solution for how to can deal with the general case.
I do not consider this solution ideal, because we guess and verify that the minimum occurs at $ x = 2$. It happens to work for this expression, and there isn't an easy tweak if the variables were changed slightly.  ]
We want to find the minimum of $ \frac{ 64}{x^2} + \frac{ 16}{x} + 65 + 16 x + x^2 $.
If we wanted to apply AM-GM with the minimum $x=2$ in mind, then we should be looking to use inequalities like

$(1): x^2 + \frac{16}{x^2} \geq 8 $
$(2): x + \frac{4}{x} \geq 4 $
$(3): 2x + \frac{ 8}{x^2} \geq 6 $
$(4): 1 \geq 1$

Claim: Show that these are sufficient for us to obtain a (positive) linear combination of them to add up to exactly $ \frac{ 64}{x^2} + \frac{ 16}{x} + 65 + 16 x + x^2 $.

 $ 1 \times (1) + 6 \times (2) + 4 \times (3)  + 65 \times (4) $

Corollary: Hence, the minimum occurs at  $ x = 2$.

We have equivalently
$$
x^2 y-(x+8)^2 \left(x^2+1\right)=0
$$
now the local minima are tangent to an horizontal line. At the tangency point we have
$$
x^2 y_0-(x+8)^2 \left(x^2+1\right)\equiv c_2(x-r)^2(x^2+c_1x+ c_0)\ \forall x
$$
the double root occurs due to tangency, so we have also
$$
\cases{
c_0 c_2 r^2+64=0\\
c_2 r (2c_0-c_1 r)-16=0\\
y_0-c_2 (c_0+r (r-2c_1))-65=0\\
2 c_2r-c_1 c_2-16=0\\
c_2+1=0
}
$$
and solving for $\{r,c_0,c_1,c_2,y_0\}$ we obtain
$$
\cases{
r = -8, c_0 = -1, c_1 = 0, c_2 = 1, y_0 = 0\\ 
r = 2, c_0 = -1, c_1 = 20, c_2 = 16, y_0 = 125
}
$$
so the solution is $y_0 = 125$ at $x = r = 2$
